# Canvas instruction invisible in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I want to create a `TextInput` and modify its canvas to have a white `RoundedRectangle` in the background. I made the `background_color` transparent, but I don't see that rectangle behind the `TextInput`.
I've tried to instead draw on `canvas.before` and `canvas.after`. The both seemed to result in one thing: the expected `Rectangle` covered the cursor and the text. And while this would be expected for canvas.after, I thought `canvas.before` wouldn't cover anything? How to make a background through canvas instructions for a `TextInput`?

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    canvas:       # no rectangle this way
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
''')

class Test(TextInput):
    pass

runTouchApp(Test())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple! You set `Color` in canvas which is set to (some?) other components too (probably via OpenGL directly). Therefore you have to "unset" it - or better said set it to the default `Color`, which you have already access to:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
Builder.load_string('''
<Test>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, .5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: root.foreground_color
    background_color: 1,1,1,0
''')
class Test(TextInput): pass
runTouchApp(Test())
```

You already have colors set in the default TextInput, so you can access them with `root.`

Also for more features play with `background_*` properties. Making an *image* with rounded corners will be probably better for a performance if you need it(mobiles) and you can switch between them just with setting those properties, because `TextInput` handles switchess automatically.